# Why is the React Native Packager not creating a new bundle when changes are saved?

Tags: macos, react-native, create-react-native-app

On Mac, I created a React Native project via [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) and then ejected the app. Then I ran `npm run ios`, which is an alias for `react-native run-ios`. At that point, I can see it start up in the simulator and the packager opens in a new terminal window. It looks like it is watching for any changes on JS files in my project directory, yet when I make a basic edit in the JSX in the `App.js` file, I don't see anything happening in the packager terminal window and it doesn't reload the app in the simulator.

Edit: I just tested it on the react-native CLI and it happens there as well. I'm at a loss what the issue could be.​​

Am I missing something or is there another issue?

[image]

Comment: Try `Cmd + R` on the simulator to check if it refreshes the bundle again in the packager.If you want to watch the changes that you save realtime you need to enable `hot reloading` from the `Cmd + D` , the `devtools` option

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I missed that part. Submit it as the answer and and I'll pick yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the app to `refresh`,  you need to do `Cmd + R` which refreshes the packager and lets it watch the refreshed bundle. For Realtime Loading, use `Cmd + D` to enable the `devtools` and enable *`Hot Reloading`*. Hope it helps!